# javascript library

Tags: javascript

which javascript library is the most recommended and why ?

Comment: You should add more informations. What do you expect from the library ?

Comment: I fear you may have provoked a flame war. http://kokuun.files.wordpress.com/2008/06/flamewar.jpg

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which JavaScript framework (jQuery vs Dojo vs ... )?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/394601/which-javascript-framework-jquery-vs-dojo-vs)

Comment: The best lib is that you've made - you know it's exact purpose and functions. :)

Comment: That depends on what you want to do. Hell, you haven't even specified client- or server-side.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I couldn't say what's *best*, per se, but I can tell you what I prefer: jQuery.

jQuery is an immensely useful library. Perhaps the most interesting and useful thing about it is that you select elements of your page to manipulate just like you do with CSS. Targeting any element with the id of "container" is as easy as $("#container"). Want all paragraphs with a shiny class? You'd use $("p.shiny").

The How jQuery Works tutorial and others, linked right here on the homepage are well written and will get you on your feet if you know some CSS and JavaScript basics.

jQuery will not replace JavaScript - it's written in JavaScript, and you still need to know something about it. The slogan is no lie - jQuery will change the way that you write JavaScript.

Comment: If you use Google's sidewiki, you'll see this same description on jquery.com, too - I wrote it :)

Comment: This is the epitome of the JS community on SO.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend a bit of **vanilla js**, after that it should be pretty easy adapting
to various styles introduced by various libraries.
jQuery is a fabulous library, but it can leave you a little underdeveloped
in terms of mastering javascript, because it does many things very easy, but not necessarily the javascript way.
**jQuery** is pretty easy to get a hang of.
After that, check out **backbone.js** and **dojo**.